# javax.validation.constraints.Pattern validating type class java.lang.String[]

Tags: java, bean-validation

I'm trying to create validation for `String[]` like below, but I'm getting an exception.

> 11:28:02,832 WARN  [http-nio-8080-exec-1] internal.ValidationExceptionMapper (ValidationExceptionMapper.java:119) - Unexpected Bean Validation problem.
>   javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Pattern' validating type 'class java.lang.String[]'. Check configuration for

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

/**
 * Created by vagrant on 3/16/18.
 */
public class ShareClassSearchRequest extends BaseSearchRequest
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Valid
    private @Pattern(regexp = InputValidationPattern.REGULAR_TEXT)String[] legalNames;

    @Valid
    private @Pattern(regexp = InputValidationPattern.INTEGER)String[] investmentProductIds;

    public String[] getLegalNames()
    {
        return legalNames;
    }

    public void setLegalNames(String[] legalNames)
    {
        this.legalNames = legalNames;
    }

    public String[] getInvestmentProductIds()
    {
        return investmentProductIds;
    }

    public void setInvestmentProductIds(String[] investmentProductIds)
    {
        this.investmentProductIds = investmentProductIds;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you can only use a Pattern on ``String``, but not ``String[]``.

Answer (score 0):

`@Pattern` cannot be applied to `String[]`.

Instead, you might replace your array with a `List`:

```
@Valid
private List<@Pattern(regexp = InputValidationPattern.REGULAR_TEXT) String> legalNames;
```

In java 7 and older, you have to create custom constraint for `String[]`

Comment: Strange, I'm getting this error.  error: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration private List<@Pattern(regexp = InputValidationPattern.REGULAR_TEXT) String>

Comment: What's your Java version. This is supported in Java 8

Comment: I'm using 1.8  openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: Did you use bean validation api version 2.0 +? You need that level to work.

Comment: Perfect! Adding this in build.gradle worked... thanks Manh..  compile(group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final')

Comment: Glad it helped. Cheer